# Display error page for HTTP 400 coming from AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, http-error, http-status-code-400

I have an application which is hosted in S3 bucket and that is exposed to the public via CloudFront. OAI is use to access the content from the S3.

In this application, we have complex URL patterns and we are getting 400 error for some of the URLs due to incorrect URLs patterns(invalid encodings, etc). Eventhough, CF is allow to set custom error pages, we cannot place a custom error page for these requests because these requests blocked from the CF level and not forwarding these requests to the OAI. As per the AWS documentation, error pages can be set for the HTTP error codes which are coming from the OAI level. Therefore, I am trying to find the solution for this issue with existing architecture. Please let me know if you have some solution for this.

I need to display a custom page for the 400 errors coming from the cloudfront

Comment: I didn't get this sentence. `we cannot place a custom error page for these requests because these requests blocked from the CF level and not forwarding these requests to the OAI.` Could you clarify?

Comment: I have placed custom error page for the CloudFront with 400. Then, I try to add invalid URL with "%2" in to the URL and try to access the site. It is giving me CloudFront error and not display the 400 page that i have configured.

Error --------------
400 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

Comment: this is what CF is telling in the AWS "You can configure CloudFront to respond to requests using a custom error page when your origin returns an HTTP 4xx or 5xx status code. For example, when your custom origin is unavailable and returning 5xx responses,"

in this case, if my request is not going to the CF due to invalid URL, can we do this ?